# Angular 5 unit test for component that calls a service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular5

I've got an Angular 5 project where I'm adding my unit tests for my login component.

The test is on my 'submit' button that will call a `REST API` to do my authentication, and if successful, returns a `JWT`.

Here's my `LoginComponent.submit` function:

```
submit() {
    this.loggingService.log('LoginComponent | submit | ...');

    this.loginService.login(this.loginFormGroup.get('username').value, this.loginFormGroup.get('password').value)
        .subscribe((jwtString: string) => {
            window.alert('login successful, token: ' + jwtString);

            // the response should be the JWT, so let's set it
            this.authenticationService.setToken(jwtString);
        }, (error: any) => { // should this be changed to the Error type on return???
            const errorString: string = error && error.message ? error.message : error;

            this.loggingService.error('login failed ' + errorString);
            this.loginFormGroup.setErrors({ 'post': errorString });
        });
}
```

Here's my `LoginService.login` function:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    this.loggingService.log('LoginService | login | loginUrl: ' + this.loginUrl + '; username: ' + username + '; password: xxxxx');

    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, { username: username, password: password });
}
```

Very straight-forward, now here's my unit test for the `LoginComponent`:

```
it('submit logs the user in successfully', () => {
    // spyOn(loginService, 'login').and.returnValue('asdfasdfasdf').and.callThrough();

    component.loginFormGroup.setValue({ username: 'roberto', password: 'password' });
    component.submit();

    expect(authenticationService.getToken()).toEqual('asdfasdfasdf');
});
```

When executing my test, I'm getting this error back:

> 'ERROR: login failed _this.handler.handle is not a function'

Now, seeing that, it makes me think it has something to do with a `middleware`. Only middleware I have is an `HttpInterceptor`, here's that code:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.loggingService.log('CustomHttpInterceptor | intercept | intercepting http(s) transaction: ' + request.urlWithParams);

        const customRequest = this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated()
            ? request.clone({
                    headers: request.headers
                        .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.getToken())
                        .set('Content-type', 'application/json')
                })
            : request.clone({
                    headers: request.headers
                        .set('Content-type', 'application/json')
                });

        return next.handle(customRequest)
            .do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                // need this if check here because the options calls are NOT an HttpResponse, and we don't want to do anything with them
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    // log a successful response from the API call
                    this.loggingService.logApiCall('CustomHttpInterceptor | intercept | ' + JSON.stringify(event));
                }
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                // log the failed response
                this.loggingService.error('CustomHttpInterceptor | intercept | ' + JSON.stringify(error));

                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {

                    // if we ever want to save our failed (401) requests, and retry after attempting to refresh the JWT,
                    // add a function to the auth service to add this HttpEvent, then after the JWT refresh, we can re-execute
                    // the http call.

                    this.router.navigate(['login']);
                }

                return Observable.throw('asdf error');
            });
    }
```

In order to get rid of that error above, I have to add this line to the beginning of my unit test (portion of this was commented out above):

```
spyOn(loginService, 'login').and.returnValue('asdfasdfasdf'); // .and.callThrough()
```

As you can see, if I set the spy to explicity return my string, then the handler error goes away, but now I get this error:

> TypeError: this.loginService.login(...).subscribe is not a function

Any thoughts here?

Edit: response to comment below...

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    loginService = TestBed.get(LoginService);
    authenticationService = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);

    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: Before `component.loginFormGroup.setValue` call, how do you instantiate your `component`?

Comment: @eminlala in a `beforeEach`, I updated the question to show that code.

Comment: Shouldn't your return value for `spyOn` be an Observable? Something like `spyOn(loginService, 'login').and.returnValue(Observable.of('asdfasdfasdf'))`.

Comment: @eminlala Oh my! Such an easy fix! Please add as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: an honest mistake, thank you!   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spyOn` should have an Observable as a return value. For example:

`spyOn(loginService, 'login').and.returnValue(Observable.of('asdfasdfasdf'))`.